# Hibernate HQL constructor expression on collection object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, constructor, expression, hql

I have following

```
Order {
  Date date, 
  String title, 
  List<Item> items
}

Item {
  String name, 
  String qty, 
  ... [other non-related information]
}
```

I can write an HQL which will return me a list of Orders with items in it.

```
SELECT order 
FROM Orders order 
  LEFT JOIN FETCH oder.items 
WHERE item.qty > 2
```

My question is, can I put Constructor Expression on "Item" to get only (name & qty)?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. What you could do, however, is use an [entity graph](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) to load only those fields from `Item`s that you're interested in.

Note that:

- You'll need to make sure entity enhancement is enabled (otherwise basic properties will still be loaded eagerly)
- Your app may not try to access any `Item` properties other than `id`, `name` and `qty` or else hibernate may try to initialize the rest of the entity properties (a db query will be issued or a `LazyInitializationException` will be thrown, depending on the entity state). This includes 'less obvious' pieces of your app such as JSON serialization libraries